# mousewheel and overflow hidden not working

Tags: jquery, mousewheel

Got an elemnt with `overflow:hidden` and an eventlistener on the mousewheel.. But nothing happens when scrolling up and down

http://jsfiddle.net/XNwbt/299/

## code

```
$( '.scrollable' ).on( 'mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function ( e ){
    var delta = e.wheelDelta || -e.detail;
    this.scrollTop += ( delta < 0 ? 1 : -1 ) * 30;
    return false;
});

.scrollable {
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background:yellow;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `delta` is `NaN`. Try to add `$.event.props.push('wheelDelta');` before your wheelhandler.

```
$.event.props.push('wheelDelta');
$('.scrollable').on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (e){
    var delta = e.wheelDelta || -e.detail;
    this.scrollTop += (delta < 0 ? 1 : -1) * 30;
    return false;
});
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/XNwbt/301/

However, I really recommend to use Brandons [mousewheel-plugin](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel)!

http://fiddle.jshell.net/XNwbt/302/

Note, that during the use of Brandons plugin, the proper way is to use the second `parameter` from the event-handler, to get the wheel-`delta`...

Comment: actually I use Brandons plugin, but it doesn't work in Firefox when the container has `overflow:hidden`.. The whole body scrolls too

Comment: @clarkk do you use your `delta`-"thing" or the second parameter from the event-handler?

Comment: I use the second `delta` parameter returned by the plugin

Comment: have solved it.. Its because I didn't use `this.scrollTop += ...` but instead `content.scrollTop += ...` Don't know why that didn't work in firefox!? but now it does :)

Comment: you don't need to use `e.preventDefault();`... just `return false;` at the end of the function :)

Answer (score 1):

this cross browser example could help you:

```
if (elem.addEventListener) {
    if ('onwheel' in document) {
        // IE9+, FF17+
        elem.addEventListener ("wheel", onWheel, false);
    } else if ('onmousewheel' in document) {
        // legacy
        elem.addEventListener ("mousewheel", onWheel, false);
    } else {
        // 3.5 <= Firefox < 17
        elem.addEventListener ("MozMousePixelScroll", onWheel, false);
    }
} else { // IE<9
    elem.attachEvent ("onmousewheel", onWheel);
}

function onWheel(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
    // wheelDelta doesn't get pixels count
    var delta = e.deltaY || e.detail || e.wheelDelta;
    var info = document.getElementById('delta');
    info.innerHTML = +info.innerHTML + delta;
    e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : (e.returnValue = false);
}
```